# Mapping to the collection based on the type (column)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have three entities: **Series, Argument, ArgumentType**.

```
public class Series : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ChangeDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Argument> LambdaArguments { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Argument> GradientArguments { get; set; }
}

public class Argument : Entity<int>
{
    public ArgumentType Type { get; set; }
    public Series Series { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class ArgumentType : Entity<int>
{
    // 'Lambda', 'Gradient' etc.
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know is it possible and how to map that **Series** entity could have a collection of each argument depened of **ArgumentType** itself:

```
public virtual ICollection<Argument> LambdaArguments { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Argument> GradientArguments { get; set; }
```

There are mappings files I got:

```
public class SeriesMap : BaseMap<Series, int>
{
    public SeriesMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.CreateDateTime).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ChangeDateTime).IsOptional();

        HasMany(x => x.Arguments);
    }
}

public class ArgumentMap : BaseMap<Argument, int>
{
    public ArgumentMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(x => x.Series);
        HasRequired(x => x.Type);
    }
}

public class ArgumentTypeMap : BaseMap<ArgumentType, int>
{
    public ArgumentTypeMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [this inheritance model](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) (Table Per Hierarchy). You would end up with these models:

```
public abstract class Argument : Entity<int>
{
    public ArgumentType Type { get; set; }
    public Series Series { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class GradientArgument: Argument 
{
    //..extra properties
}

public class LambdaArgument: Argument 
{
    //..extra properties
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ArgumentMap : BaseMap<Argument, int>
{
    public ArgumentMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(x => x.Series);
        HasRequired(x => x.Type);
         Map<Argument>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Course"))
            .Map<GradientArgument>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("GradientArgument"))
            .Map<LambdaArgument>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("LambdaArgument"));
    }
}
```

Then you can attach either Argument types to your `Series` entity. You will have to cast the type to retrieve any custom properties.